# Which IDE (Android Studio and Visual Code) is better in terms of less memory consumption for Android application development?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, android-studio, ram

I have 4GB RAM and Intel HD graphics so suggest to me in that way which one to choose between Android Studio and Visual Code for android app dev.?

Comment: VC is not Android Studio. For better productivity you better use Android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Code itself doesn't support creating Android projects. You need to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adelphes.android-dev-ext) to have ***some*** Android development features which are seriously limited compared to the Android Studio.

You can use the Android Studio with 4GB of RAM without having much headache unless you are dealing with really large projects and/or using the Android Emulator at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

Just check minimum system requirements:
Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio
Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

It looks like Android Studio recommends 8gb of RAM and Visual Studio 1gb

But the best idea is to check both and check which one works better for you and which one suits you better